# Creating custom HTML element with attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I know how I can create a custom HTML Tag in JS. But what if I want it to have some attributes? For example:

```
<custom-tag text="Foo and Bar"></custom-tag>
```

should be shown as:

```
<section>Foo and Bar</section>
```

What would be the cleanest way for doing this? I know it has to work if I loop through all custom-tag elements in JS. But I'm sure ther must be a better way...

Comment: Look into setAttribute() but I don't know if that will work on custom elements.

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic, use jQuery or DOMParser to parse your custom tag, then build up the valid HTML as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using frameworks

You can use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). This framework supports this feature.

Other option, using [jQuery](https://jquery.com), is the following:

HTML:

```
<custom-tag text="Foo and Bar"></custom-tag>
```

Javascript:

```
var text = $('custom-tag').attr('text');
$('custom-tag').replaceWith('<section>'+text+'</section>');
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/ces/pen/EjpONy

#### Vanilla Javascript

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('custom-tag')[0];
var attr = element.getAttribute('text');

var section = document.createElement('section');
section.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;

element.parentNode.insertBefore(section, element);
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
section.innerHTML = attr;
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/ces/pen/bdjQqO

Comment: This can easily be done with plain javascript and not Angular or jQuery.

Comment: @Rob and how would you do this?

Comment: Hm ok. So the only working way is to loop through all the elements. Thank you :)